# Different exposure on video and screen

Tags: swift, opengl-es, avfoundation

I capture video from a camera device and draw it to screen and save on AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate.captureOutput method.
I use `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()` for creating OpenGL texture for rendering and `AVAssetWriterInput` for saving video.

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
     createTexture(sampleBuffer)
     inputWriter.append(sampleBuffer)
 }
```

Problem is on scene lighting(exposure) - it is different on video and screen.

[image]